Laravel: how to sort base on relationship column
We have Student Model. The Student Model hasMany relationship with Grade Model
Here are columns:
Student - id, level, name, status
Grade - id, student_id, subject, grade, status
Basically what I'm trying to do is query all the first level students that took math1 subject and sort it with grades
Here is my code so far:
$r = Student::where("level", 1)
           ->whereRelation('grades', 'subject', 'math1')
           ->get();

This works on filtering the first level students with math1 subject but my question is how can i sort base on relatioship grade column?
Thanks in advance.

My first thought was that I'd actually reverse this, if your main interest is the grades. When you know that you want to list all Students taking the math1 class, you could do something like this:
Grade::with('Student')
    ->whereSubject('math1')
    ->whereHas('Student', fn($query) => $query->whereLevel(1))
    ->orderBy('grade')
    ->get();


option-1: another way is
//Grade model with relation function 
public function StudentMathLevel1()
{
    return $this->belongsTo(Student::class)->where('level',1)->where('subject','math1');
}

usage in controller
Grade::with('StudentMathLevel1')->orderBy('grade')->get();

==============================
option-2: Further, you can also try the Scope functional approach
//Grade model with relation function using 'scope'
public function scopeStudentSpecificSubjectLevel($subject, $level)
{
    return $this->belongsTo(Student::class)->where('level',$level)->where('subject',$subject);
}

usage in controller
Grade::StudentSpecificSubjectLevel('math1',1)->orderBy('grade')->get();

